# How do I write a Python code to check if the given sequence is a palindrome or not?

Tags: python, arrays, string, reverse, palindrome

I wish to learn more about the rev_string

I tried to see if "MOM" is a palindrome and I wanted the result to be yes/no

Comment: I search first: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28118244/1766544 although I would prefer iterators and just compare s vs reversed(s) one character at a time

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check for palindrome using Python logic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17331290/how-to-check-for-palindrome-using-python-logic)

Answer (score 2):

It's very simple, First, you need to reverse the `String` that you want to check whether it's a palindrome or not. Then Compare the reverse `String` with the input one. If it's the same then it's a palindrome else it's not.

```
string = "MoM"
revstring = "".join(reversed(string))

print("Yes" if string == revstring else "No")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
s=input()
if s==s[::-1]:
    print("Yes")
else:
    print("No")
```

Explanation:

In line 1 we have taken a string "s" as an input.
Reverse of s is given by slicing by s[::-1].
Then from line 2 a block of code executes and check if "s" is a palindrome or not.